# Redirect to signin page and display the message in that page only

Tags: javascript, php

I have this JavaScript code, in this scenario if **data.rval == 2** then it should redirect to **signin** page and display the message in that page only

```
if(data.rval == 1) {
            window.location = "/offerletter/index";
            Application.PageAlertBox.Show('Sucess', ['Successfully Loggedin.']);
        } else if(data.rval == 2) {
            window.location = "/signin";
            Application.PageAlertBox.Show('info', ['OTP is Expired, New OTP has been sent on official email id, Please try again.']);
        } else if(data.rval == -4) {
            Application.PageAlertBox.Show('error', ['OTP is Invalid. Please Enter correct OTP.']);
        } else {
            Application.PageAlertBox.Show('error', [data.Message]);
        }
```

Comment: and the problem is....?

Comment: Please, do not forget to escape that variable :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(data.rval == 1) {
        window.location = "/offerletter/index";
        Application.PageAlertBox.Show('Sucess', ['Successfully Loggedin.']);
    } else if(data.rval == 2) {
        window.location = "/signin?info=OTP is Expired, New OTP has been sent on official email id, Please try again.";
    } else if(data.rval == -4) {
        Application.PageAlertBox.Show('error', ['OTP is Invalid. Please Enter correct OTP.']);
    } else {
        Application.PageAlertBox.Show('error', [data.Message]);
    }
```

and in the signin page:

```
Application.PageAlertBox.Show('info', ['<?php echo $_GET['info']?>']);
```